# Operation across observations and year is returned NaN

Tags: python, pandas, return, panel

I have a panel dataset with a set of countries [Italy and US] for 3 years and two numeric variables `['Var1', 'Var2']`. I would like to calculate the rate of change in the last three years Ex: the value for Var1 in 2019 minus the value of Var1 in 2017 divided by Var1 in 2017.

I do not understand why my code (below) returns NaN errors?

```py
data = {'Year':[2017, 2018, 2019, 2017, 2018, 2019], 'Country':['Italy', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'US' ,  'US', 'US'], 'Var1':[23,75,45, 32,13,14], 'Var2':[21,75,47, 30,11,18]}
trend = pd.DataFrame(data) 
list = ['Var1', 'Var2']
for col in list:
    trend[col + ' (3 Year % Change)'] = ((trend.loc[trend['Year']==2019][col]- trend.loc[trend['Year']==2017][col])/trend.loc[trend['Year']==2017][col])*100

trend
```

Comment: Do you want every year compared to 2017? or to the previous year?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things going wrong here with your code:

1. You are trying to divide `pd.series` and not only their arrays, and they are carrying their index, which causes the division to become `NaN`
2. If you actually pass the values, for instance by using `.values` after the columns filters, you will bump into a `ValueError` because you want two values to insert into the entire `DataFrame` and `pandas` won't like that (length should be the same). This exemplifies it:

```py
trend.loc['Var1' + ' (3 Year % Change)'] = ((trend.loc[trend['Year']==2019, 'Var1'].values - \
                                        trend.loc[trend['Year']==2017, 'Var1'].values)/\
                                        trend.loc[trend['Year']==2017, 'Var1'].values)*100
```

> ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns

3. Not sure if you are using `list` as an actual variable name, but that is a reserved `python` word. It is not the best idea. You can read about it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-Reserved-Keywords-in-Python)

If you want to compare the values with `2017` values in your sample, you can use 
`groupby`+`shift`, based on how many years to shift:

```py
for col in ['Var1','Var2']:
    trend[col + ' (3 Year % Change)'] = (trend[col] - trend.groupby('Country').shift(2)[col])/trend.groupby('Country').shift(2)[col]

Out[1]:
   Year Country  Var1  Var2  Var1 (3 Year % Change)  Var2 (3 Year % Change)
0  2017   Italy    23    21                     NaN                     NaN
1  2018   Italy    75    75                     NaN                     NaN
2  2019   Italy    45    47                0.956522                1.238095
3  2017      US    32    30                     NaN                     NaN
4  2018      US    13    11                     NaN                     NaN
5  2019      US    14    18               -0.562500               -0.400000
```

Comment: thanks, it worked! and thanks for the explanation, very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Check if this gives what you want. It is much simpler to understand.

```
trend['Var1_3_Year_%_Change'] = trend.groupby('Country')['Var1'].apply(lambda x : ((x-x.iloc[0]))/x.iloc[0]*100)
trend['Var2_3_Year_%_Change'] = trend.groupby('Country')['Var2'].apply(lambda x : ((x-x.iloc[0]))/x.iloc[0]*100)
trend['Var1_yearly'] = trend.groupby('Country')['Var1'].apply(lambda x : ((x-x.shift()))/x.shift()*100)
trend['Var2_yearly'] = trend.groupby('Country')['Var2'].apply(lambda x : ((x-x.shift()))/x.shift()*100)
```

**Output**

```
Year    Country     Var1    Var2    Var1_3_Year_%_Change    Var2_3_Year_%_Change    Var1_yearly     Var2_yearly
2017    Italy   23  21  0.000000    0.000000    NaN     NaN
2018    Italy   75  75  226.086957  257.142857  226.086957  257.142857
2019    Italy   45  47  95.652174   123.809524  -40.000000  -37.333333
2017    US  32  30  0.000000    0.000000    NaN     NaN
2018    US  13  11  -59.375000  -63.333333  -59.375000  -63.333333
2019    US  14  18  -56.250000  -40.000000  7.692308    63.636364
```

If it has to be done with for loop, use

```
var= ['Var1','Var2']
for col in var:
trend[col + ' (3 Year % Change)'] = trend.groupby('Country')[col].apply(lambda x : ((x-x.iloc[0]))/x.iloc[0]*100)
```

Comment: this is great and it would work, but in real life I have several numeric variables (more than just to). I tried you approach with a loop but it gave me an error: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1 .. how to solve it?

Comment: this will work for any number of rows. `(x-x.iloc[0])` is the difference between the current row & the first row (of the same column), so it will work irrespective of any number of rows. Same with `x-x.shift()`, this is the difference between value in current row & the value in the previous row. This will also irrespective of any number of rows.